# Next.js with Router DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

I want to take the result of the code in navigation but it seems to return an horrible error: Unhandled Runtime Error

> Error: You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`. You
> should never have more than one in your app.

```
"use client";
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from '@/components/main/Main';
import Sidebar from "@/components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import { Blog } from "@/pages/blog/Blog";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Sidebar />
      <Main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/blog/[id]" element={<Blog />} />
        </Routes>
      </Main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

I tried to take the result but i can't please help me

Comment: There is already a router in NextJS. Why do you want another one?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue here is that the `Home` component is recursively rendering itself. This results in a router nesting inside another router.

```
"use client";

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from '@/components/main/Main';
import Sidebar from "@/components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import { Blog } from "@/pages/blog/Blog";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Sidebar />
      <Main>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<Home />} // <-- renders Home again!
          />
          <Route path="/blog/:id" element={<Blog />} />
        </Routes>
      </Main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

## Solution

Update the `"/"` route to render anything but another `Home` component, or remove it if you don't need it.

```
"use client";

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from '@/components/main/Main';
import Sidebar from "@/components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import { Blog } from "@/pages/blog/Blog";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Sidebar />
      <Main>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={/* Anything other than Home again */} // <--
          />
          <Route path="/blog/:id" element={<Blog />} />
        </Routes>
      </Main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```